# Access to an array using a list

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array A and a list b. I want to put number c in the location b of array A. For example, assume

```
import numpy
size = 4
size_maker = [2] * size
A = numpy.zeros(shape=size_maker)

b = [0,1,0,0]
c = 20
```

I want to have A[0,1,0,0] = 20. Any idea?

Comment: In your example, `A` is a 4D array of _one_ element. You probably wanted to use `size_maker = [2] * size`.

Comment: @DYZ you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a tuple instead of a list.

```
A[tuple(b)] = c
```